# Form submits when "<button>" is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an Account Create form. There is no submit button, just a `<button>`. Right now I have a jQuery validation running when the button is clicked. The validation is being run and the proper errors show up for it, but the form is then submitted and the page reloaded. Even though I have no submit button and not jQuery `submit()` function anywhere.

HTML:

```
<form id="accountCreate" method="POST" action="<?=site_url('account/create')?>">
    <h3>Create an Account</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email..." /></li>
        <li><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password" /></li>
        <li><input type="password" placeholder="Verify Password..." id="verifyPassword" /></li>
        <li><button id="button">Create</button></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button').click(function() { 
    var password = $('input#password').val();
    var passwordV = $('input#passwordVerify').val();

    if (password.length >= 6 && password.length <= 24) {
        if (password == passwordV) {

        } else {
            $('div#error').css('display', 'inline');
            $('div#error span.errorMessage').text('hey');
        }
    } else {
        alert('yo');
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a default `type=` attribute for the button, as different browsers can use different defaults. In your case, it looks like the browser has defaulted to `type="submit"`.

Comment: That's it. Thanks. I think the other guy answered first though.

Comment: @DylanButh, Doesn't matter, as long as you get your answer. Mouseover the `answered .. ago` line to see seconds if you *really* want to be picky. :)

Comment: Oh, looks like you were 22 seconds faster.

Answer (score 5):

When no `type` attribute is defined a `<button />` acts as a submit button.
Add `type="button"` to fix this problem.

```
<button id="button" type="button">Create</button>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.html#button

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button').click(function() { 
var password = $('input#password').val();
var passwordV = $('input#passwordVerify').val();

if (password.length >= 6 && password.length <= 24) {
    if (password == passwordV) {

    } else {
        $('div#error').css('display', 'inline');
        $('div#error span.errorMessage').text('hey');
    }
} else {
    alert('yo');
    return false;
}
//Just add return false
return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `evt.preventDefault();` to make the submit only do what you want.